# Como inserir no mysql usando foreach?

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, tenho um código onde pego os dados vindo de um webservice e guardo em variáveis.

Eu gostaria de `Inserir/Salvar` esses dados no meu banco de dados *MySQL*. No entanto eu pego esses dados através de um `foreach(){...}`

```
// Pegar os leads
    $leads = $client->leads->getLeads([]);

// Pegando os leads
    foreach($leads->contacts as $contacts)
    {
        // Salvando dados nas variáveis
            $nome    = $contacts->name;
            $id      = $contacts->id;
            $tags    = $contacts->tags;

        // Percorrendo os dados
            foreach($tags->tags as $objeto)
            {
                $tag  = $objeto->name;
            }   
    }
```

dê acordo com o código acima. Como eu poderia inserir esses dados de forma que ficaria assim na tabela *[exemplo ]* :

> `[ID] [NOME] [TAGS]`
>
> `[01] [JOSÉ] [tag1,tag2,tag3..]`

Pois se eu criar uma query assim :

> `$query = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO leads(nome,tags) VALUES ('$nome','$tag')";`

cada `foreach(){..}` teria uma *tag* diferente e ***sobrescreveria*** o valor da *tag* anterior.

Comment: Verifique aí. Não existe a clausula WHERE no insert.

Comment: Opa amigo, verdade acabei me confundindo com o `If(){...}` que faz a verificação se existe o usuário com o `ID` se existir atualize senão Insere um novo! Obrigado pela observação!

Comment: `$contacts->tags` é um array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ao invés de você percorrer a lista de *tags* de cada registro, sendo elas um vetor, você pode torná-las um objeto único, no formato JSON, e armazená-las apenas de uma vez para cada resgistro.

```
$leads = $client->leads->getLeads([]);

foreach($leads->contacts as $contacts)
{
    $nome    = $contacts->name;
    $id      = $contacts->id;
    $tags    = $contacts->tags;

    // Aqui você serializa o vetor de tags:
    $tags = json_encode($tags);

    // Agora execute a sua *query* de INSERT:
    $query = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO leads(nome, tags) VALUES ('$nome', '$tags')");

}
```

Desta forma, será salvado no banco de dados as *tags* no formato semelhante à `[tag1, rag2, tag3...]`, com os colchetes. Na hora de recuperar os dados do banco, basta executar `$tags = json_decode($tags)` que você possuirá o vetor de *tags* novamente.

Comment: Hahaha perfeito meu amigo @Anderson muito obrigado  pela sua resposta!

Comment: mysqli_query != mysql_query

Answer (score 1):

## Pode usar o `Implode`

Você pode usar o [implode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) do `php` para juntar as tags e gravar num campo `varchar`.

```
$tags = implode(",", $contacts->tags);
```

Se precisar fazer `Insert` ou `Update` pode usar um comando `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` do MySQL. Veja um exemplo [nessa questão do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists#4205207) (em inglês)

Answer (score 0):

Se `$contacts->tags;` for um array use `implode`:

```
$leads = $client->leads->getLeads([]);

foreach($leads->contacts as $contacts)
{
    $nome    = $contacts->name;
    $id      = $contacts->id;
    $tags    = implode(',', $contacts->tags);

    // Aqui você serializa o vetor de tags:
    $tags = json_encode($tags);

    // Agora execute a sua *query* de INSERT:
    $query = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO leads(nome,tags) VALUES ('$nome','$tags')";

}
```

E quando for ler do banco use `explode`, algo semelhante a isto:

```
explode(',', $row['tags']);
```